# next/image not displaying any images after deploy to firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-hosting, web-development-server

The images load and display well on npm run dev but after deploying my project non of them is displaying

I'm using the next/image to upload the images, I stored them in an Assets folder
I'm assessing in a format of src='/Assets/car.jpg'

How can I solve this!

I've tried placing the images directly to the project folder instead of having an Assets folder right in it, but when I did that I noticed the images won't even be in the out directory which is where firebase serve the content from

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the hostname of your firebase host to next config:

```
const nextConfig = {
...
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [{
            hostname: 'whatever.your.firebase.host.is'
        }]
    },
...
}
```

Also some log would be nice if this doesn't help.